# create a rule for more than one use inside a regex call

Tags: regex, format, rule, textselection

Supposing I have the following text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod ,,,,,,tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis ,,,,,nostrud exercitation ullamco [,] laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu [,,,,,] fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint {,,}occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt {,,,,,} in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id ,,,,,est laborum.

I would like to select all commas in the text with the following pattern

```
(\,{2,99})
```

but then I also would like to specify the same filter to be applied only between specific characters like selecting only the commas between `[]` or `{}` but not `[}` for example.

where this would fail:

```
(\[|\{)  (\,{2,99})  (\]|\})
```

and the following would work as expected

```
(\{)  (\,{2,99})  (\})  |  (\[)  (\,{2,99})  (\])
```

so the thing is that I am having to re-type `(\,{2,99})` every time I want to surround this match with another selection.

Is there any way to declare inside the same command a `variable` that could be applied later on? like:

```
$1=(\,{2,99}) | (\{$1\}) | (\[$1\])
```

I hope this is easy to understand, please bear with me since regular expersions are really a new thing in my case, so all these declarations might look terrible for you :)

I would appreciate if you could notice something badly written here and recommend a better way to it.

Please also mind that this example for catching all the commas was for demonstrative purposes on how I would like to re-use a bit of code more times inside the same command...you could replace that simple selector with something huge that you wouldn't like to re-type every time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why maximum `99`? You can use `\,{2,}`

Comment: ah thanks Gabi Purcaru :), I was struggling on that one too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable and concatenate it several times with your regex.

Comment: you mean declaring it outside the regular expression? like javascript for example, and then add it to the `new RegExp(variable...)`;

Answer (score 0):

This was a tricky one.  It should work but might depend on which regex engine you are using.  It looks horible though.

```
(?=[{[])(\{)?(\[)?(,{2,})(?(1)\})(?(2)\])
```

Explanation:

```
(?=[{[])    #Look ahead to check that the next charactor is in your set of opening brackets
             # but do not capture the charactor yet.

(\{)?        #Try to capture a {

(\[)?        #Try to capture a [

(,{2,})      #The commas (or whatever else you like).
             #Note that these are only writen once.

(?(1)\})     #If you previously captured the { then also capture a }

(?(2)\])     #If you previously captured the [ then also capture a ]
```

Comment: I have tested this out and is working with the .NET framework, but it seams that JavaScript does not support it.

Comment: thanks Buh Buh, it surely look a bit complex :) it is a shame it won't work with javascript tho since it is the environment I am using. but thanks for your help there.

Answer (score 0):

The solution also depends on the quality of your data. If you can guarantee that a "[,,,,}" for example does not appear, you don't need a complicated regex.

```
[\[\{](,{2,})[\]\}]
```

would do it then. Also, you wanted to select only commas, so I only used brackets around them in this regex.